# General code design: shared and alternating patterns

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns

**The situation**
My question applies to all programming languages with classes and inheritance. Im sure the answer is out there somewhere already, but I could not find it as i don’t have the right terminology to use.

Lets take the classic example. We got Dogs and Cats which are both of the type Animal:

```
abstract class Animal {
}

class Dog extends Animal {
}

class Cat extends Animal {
}
```

Simple enough. Some behavior is shared in the `Animal` class, anything that differs between `Cat` and `Dog` is coded in their respective classes.

Now suppose we got 2 planets. Earth and Mars. Both planets have Cats and Dogs. But, behavior for all animals on Earth differs from all animals on Mars. They, for example, experience a difference in gravity which affects the way they move.

There is no difference between specific animal types between the planets. Thus, all differences between animals on Earth and Mars can be coded at the parent level, that of the `Animal` class.

Not only that, but some behavior is available for all `Animal` instances on Mars that does not exist on Earth.

Ideally, in code dealing with these animals, we deal with a `MarsAnimal` or `EarthAnimal` class that is implemented by either a `Dog` or `Cat`. The implementing code does not need to know if they are Dogs or Cats. It does already know on what planet the Animal lives though.

**What I thought about already**
One solution would be the following:

```
abstract class Animal {
}
abstract class Cat extends Animal {
}
abstract class Dog extends Animal {
}
interface MarsAnimal {
}
interface EarthAnimal {
}
class MarsCat extends Cat implements MarsAnimal {
}
class MarsDog extends Dog implements MarsAnimal {
}
class EarthCat extends Cat implements EarthAnimal {
}
class EarthDog extends Dog implements EarthAnimal {
}
```

Ofc, the obvious problem with this is, that any behavior specific to `MarsAnimal` would need to be implemented in both the `MarsCat` and `MarsDog` classes. That’s ugly code duplication and definitely not what I was looking for.

The only semi-acceptable method I could think of was the following:

```
abstract class Animal {

    private PlanetAnimal planetAnimal;

    public function myBehavior() {
        this.planetAnimal.myBehavior();
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
}

class Dog extends Animal {
}

interface PlanetAnimal {
    function myBehavior();
}

class MarsAnimal implements PlanetAnimal {
    public function myBehavior() {
        // marsAnimal- specific behavior here
    }
}

class EarthAnimal implements PlanetAnimal {
    public function myBehavior() {
        // earthAnimal- specific behavior here
    }
}
```

Thus, when creating a `Cat` or `Dog` instance, since we know what planet they are from at that point in the code, we give them the needed `PlanetAnimal` instance in their constructor (either `MarsAnimal` or `EarthAnimal`).

This is close. The only problem with this is, like I said, some behavior exists only for all animals on Mars. I’d have to still implement a method in both the `Animal` and `PlanetAnimal` classes that is used only for Mars. If this is the only solution then sure, but it feels like there should be some better method out there.

So, any ideas? I’d love to hear!

**Edit 1**
Based on questions, a small clarification: the main problem here is how to implement shared behavior between many different categories. There is shared behavior:

1. between all animals on all planets;
2. between all animals on a specific planet;
3. between all animals of a specific type (i.e. Cat or Dog), irrespective of what planet they are on

**Edit 2**
I work mainly in Java and PHP. This question specifically was asked after I encountered this in PHP, though I know I had similar situations in Java too. I know, for PHP, my first proposed solution could work in combination with Traits. That might even be where I end up. But, everywhere online I saw people warning against the use of Traits, saying it is almost always/ always bad code design. That's why I'm searching for the best solution

Comment: MarsX can extend MarsAnimal if you wanted code specific to the planet. Why use an interface? However, `class Planet` and `PlanetAnimal` makes more sense here, with two instances of planet, and 4 animals. Not 6 classes

Comment: Point your favourite search engine at *multiple inheritance*. Then move to functional programming ...

Comment: @OneCricketeer because they also have shared behavior between Earth and Mars cats, that would not work

Comment: `PlanetAnimal marsCat = new PlanetAnimal(Planets.MARS, "cat");` or `MarsAnimal("cat")` `marsCat.behavior()`... What is specific here?

Comment: @OneCricketeer actually implementing this would turn into very ugly code, though. Functions need to override other functions, having everything in 1 place means `if` checks everywhere for planet and animal type

Comment: @OneCricketeer to be clear: There is shared behaviour: 1) between all animals on all planets, 2) between all animals on a specific planet, 3) between all animals of a specific type (i.e. Cat or Dog), irrespective of what planet they are on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is a design pattern called the Strategy pattern. The pattern is defined as follows:

The Strategy pattern defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each one, and makes them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.

In your case, the Animal class would be the context, and the PlanetAnimal class would be the strategy. The context would be responsible for delegating to the correct strategy for each concrete implementation. In your example, the context would be the Animal class, and the strategy would be the PlanetAnimal class. The context would be responsible for delegating to the correct strategy for each concrete implementation.

Something like this, in Python:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animalStrategy):
        self.animalStrategy = animalStrategy
    
    def walking(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Cat(Animal):
    def walking(self):
        return self.animalStrategy.walking(canJump=True, canFly=False, canSwim=False, speed=10)

class Bird(Animal):
    def walking(self):
        return self.animalStrategy.walking(canJump=True, canFly=True, canSwim=False, speed=20, walkSpeed=2)

class MarsAnimalStrategy:
    def walking(self, canJump, canFly, canSwim, speed):
        return f"walking on Mars with speed {speed}"

class EarthAnimalStrategy:
    def walking(self, canJump, canFly, canSwim, speed, walkSpeed):
        return f"walking on Earth with speed {speed} and walkSpeed {walkSpeed}"

marsCat = Cat(MarsAnimalStrategy())
marsCat.walking()

earthCat = Cat(EarthAnimalStrategy())
earthCat.walking()
```

In this way, the Animal class is not responsible for knowing how to walk on Mars or Earth, but instead delegates that responsibility to the strategy. The strategy is responsible for knowing how to walk on Mars or Earth. The context/"user" is responsible for delegating to the correct strategy for each concrete instance.

I wouldn't go into details, but consider using a composition of objects instead of class inheritance. In short, each descendant class of `Animal` would have to be fully tested, including an internal behavior of a parent class, and `Animal` could easily become a God Object, which is not a good thing. Alternatively:

```
class IAnimal: # Python have only classes, but consider it as an interface
    def walking(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
    def eating(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    # etc.

class Cat(IAnimal):
    def __init__(self, physicalBody, livingEntity):
        self.physicalBody = physicalBody
        self.livingEntity = livingEntity

    def walking(self):
        direction = self.livingEntity.goalDirection()
        if self.physicalBody.canMove(direction):
            self.physicalBody.move(direction)
            return self.livingEntity.movedTo(self.physicalBody.position)
        
        return self.livingEntity.wasFrustrated()
```

Now `Cat` is responsible only for its own behavior, and `PhysicalBody` and `LivingEntity` are responsible for their own behavior. This way, you can easily test each class separately, and you can easily replace `PhysicalBody` and `LivingEntity` with other implementations, without changing `Cat` class. I would repeat, that now `Cat` class is highly focused solely on its own behavior and implementation of `IAnimal` interface/contract. Now, of course, you need to type `self.physicalBody.canMove(direction)` instead of `self.canMove(direction)`, but it's a small price to pay for a better design. Differences in the behavior of Earth and Mars animals would now be represented by different implementations of `LivingEntity` classes, that could share some common parts.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I need to sit down and see how I would implement it in my (actual) situation, and prob learn some more about this Strategy design. It seems my second solution was already close to doing this, this is just taking that idea a lot further. Might have some further questions later if u don't mind, for now, this is the accepted solution.

Comment: the first problem I see with this though is the Animal interface. It would have to contain methods for all contexts, even behavior that is only available on either Mars or Earth still should be in the interface, or else the User cannot use it. That was one of the main things i was trying to avoid. Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: Let's take my example to the max lol. On Mars, water is frozen., Therefore, all Animal types on Mars have evolved to warm up water, after which they can drink it. Drinking water itself is something animals on both Earth and Mars can do, but warming it up only all Animals on Mars are able to do. How would I fit this into this Strategy pattern?

Comment: Where the analogy falls apart slightly, is that all Animals on Mars warm up the water in the exact same way. There is no need for different water-warming implementations between Mars Birds and Mars Cats, for example. To be clear, all this is really asking how to answer my question at "some behavior is available for all `Animal` instances on Mars that does not exist on Earth", later clarified in Edit 1, point 2

Comment: There is no single solution, its highly depends on your preferences, concerns and goals. Usually, programmers don't bother and just throw exceptions if some method is not supported. Another solution is creating a bunch of interfaces and dynamically checking which one is supported (see Visitor pattern, btw). In this case, you are obtaining pretty strong typing, so (in some languages) you would be noticed by a compiler if you would try to call an unsupported method. I may continue, but I think you got the idea.